# "No source code lines were found at current PC 0x74e." with double in MPLAB X

Tags: c, floating-point

Need some help with a simple calculation done on a PIC24FJ128GB204.
Using MPLAB X 5.2, XC16 compiler, ICD4.

I have a sensor that returns data in 6 bytes: [temp MSB][temp LSB][CRC][humidityMSB][humidityLSB][crc]

Formula for the temp (RC = raw counts): T(deg C) = -45 +175*(RC/(2^16-1))
As too often is the case, I had it working correctly, but somehow changed something and cannot find the issue.

My function:

```
int8_t SHT31_ConvertData(  uint8_t MeasurementData[],
                        int16_t * TempResult, 
                        uint8_t * RHResult){
    // converts data from raw counts to temp (deg C) and RH (%)

//    __attribute__((aligned(2))) double TempCelcius = 0;
    double TempCelcius = 0;
    uint16_t TempRaw,RHRaw = {0};
    double RH = 0;

    // combine both bytes to get raw temperature value
    TempRaw = (MeasurementData[0] << 8);
    TempRaw += MeasurementData[1];
    TempCelcius = TempRaw;
    TempCelcius /= 0xFFFF;
    TempCelcius *= 175;
    TempCelcius -= 45;
    TempCelcius *= 100;
    *TempResult = (int)TempCelcius;

    // combine both bytes to get raw relative humidity value
    RHRaw = (MeasurementData[3] << 8);
    RHRaw += MeasurementData[4];
    RH = RHRaw;
    RH /= 0xFFFF;
    RH *= 100;
    *RHResult = RH;

    return 1;
}
```

While debugging I sometimes (say 50% of the time) have an issue with the calculations, most often at the
`TempCelcius = TempRaw;` or `TempCelcius /= 0xFFFF;` lines.

The debugger console will have lines such as *"No source code lines were found at current PC 0x74e. Open program memory view to see instruction code disassembly."*
The instruction for that address in the program memory would be (for example) `ADD W8, W8, W8`. There would always be a command at that memory location.

I don't have enough background yet to solve this myself, so far I found the following possible causes:

- Vcap with too high an ESR (checked)
- WDT on (checked, HW also disabled in pragmas)
- Unhandled interrupt (added _DefaultInterrupt with breakpoint to check)
- Accessing word or long at an odd address (thus address error exception) (don't really understand this completely. Tried `__attribute__((aligned(2))) double TempCelcius = 0;` hoping to align.)
- Division by 0 (not the case, I think)
- Bad initialized pointers (given my proficiency in C, that could be the case, but I don't use pointers in that part of code)
- SFR window open while debugging (is closed.)

What could be the issue? If necessary, will post pragmas, memory map, ...

Comment: How do you use this function? What arguments do you pass? What are their values? You're not going out of bounds of your array, or using invalid pointers? Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: The function is called with a pointer to an uint8[6] array MeasurementData containing the MSB/LSB and CRC for both measurements. Typical values are such as: 64, 40, 8a, 64, 1b, c5. TempResult and RHResult are pointer to where the data should be written. I don't think I am going out of bounds of my array as I don't change it. Invalid pointers: error occurs before the pointers are used. I will work on a minimal example and add to the question. Thanks!

Comment: `(MeasurementData[0] << 8);`  this is always 0 !!!

Comment: Although I wouldn't claim certainty that what I'm doing is according to best practices, that part does work I'm afraid. Combining MSB and LSB works as expected. I think because MeasurementData[0] gets converted to uint16_t since the left part of the equation is uint16_t?

Comment: @Mike - Can you please substantiate your assertion about `(MeasurementData[0] << 8);` is always zero?

Comment: The input values you provide in the second comment, for example `64` , if MSB is` 0x6`, and LSB is` 0x4` then would `TempRaw` (by the shown calculation) be `1540`?  If that is the case, then dividing it by 65536 (`oxffff`)would make it forever `0`.  At that point, the only value left is the -45.  I would double check your algorithm implementation.